# Max record in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to record data from the GPS in the form of latitude and longitude into the mysql database for every minute of a month. which if I count the amount of data recorded will be 43200 records per column. can that amount of data be recorded in the mysql database? how much maximum data per column can be recorded to MySQL database?

Comment: Surely you mean 4300 rows, not columns? (If not, rethink your design. If yes, then it is absolutely tiny, no worries.)

Comment: sorry typo. I mean 43200 rows, it is okay?

Comment: Facebook, Google, and Amazon all use MySQL (albeit modified versions of the core application) for substantial aspects of their data storage and retrieval. I'm pretty sure that some of those data sets exceed 43200 rows.

Comment: (I hope you're not thinking of having 12 columns - one for each month!?!?)

Comment: huh? not. I only have columns for latitude and longitude where each column contains approximately 43200 rows for one month. if it is the next month the record will be updated again

Comment: Back in 2012, I had a table with 300 million rows in MySQL. Yeah, 43200 rows will be OK.